# Sort JS array by number of unique entries in seperate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

So, I have an array of words. Lets say

```js
const wordList = [    
    "aa",
    "aah",
    "aahed",
    "aahing",
    "aahs",
    "aal",
    "aalii",
    "aaliis",
    "aals",
    "aardvark",
    "aardvarks",
    "aardwolf",
    "aardwolves",
    "aargh",
    "aarrgh",
    "aarrghh",
    "aarti",
    "aartis",
    "aas",
    "aasvogel",
    "aasvogels",
]
```

Now, lets say I have a separate array of letters A-Y (excluding X) called `letters`

What I want to do is sort `wordList` by the amount of elements of `letters` it contains.
Here, `"arrdwolved"` would be ranked considerably high because it has 9 **unique** letters (as in, letters are only counted once). Then, the letters in the first element of `wordlist` get removed from the array until there are elements in `letters` left, where it resets `letters`

Any ideas of how to do this? I am drawing an absolute blank here.

I imagine you could loop through every letter in each string, keeping a list of letters already "scored," and then sorting based on that, but I don't have a clue how I would implement this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get the number of unique characters, then use [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const wordList=["aa","aah","aahed","aahing","aahs","aal","aalii","aaliis","aals","aardvark","aardvarks","aardwolf","aardwolves","aargh","aarrgh","aarrghh","aarti","aartis","aas","aasvogel","aasvogels"];

const numOfUnique = (s) => new Set(s).size
const result = wordList.sort((a, b) => numOfUnique(b) - numOfUnique(a))
console.log(result)
```

To filter out letters that aren't in the letter list, you can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) when getting the number of unique letters:

```js
const wordList=["aa","aah","aahed","aahing","aahs","aal","aalii","aaliis","aals","aardvark","aardvarks","aardwolf","aardwolves","aargh","aarrgh","aarrghh","aarti","aartis","aas","aasvogel","aasvogels"];

const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'y']
const numOfUnique = (s) => [...new Set(s)].filter(e => letters.includes(e)).length
const result = wordList.sort((a, b) => numOfUnique(b) - numOfUnique(a))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: It looks like this answer and the one that came later from @NinaScholz both neglect the letter list, which apparently qualifies which letters to count in the unique set. Simple fix (for both) is to first filter the strings to include only letters from letter list before counting uniques.

Comment: @danh didn't notice that, thanks!

Comment: It works, but it gets really slow as the number of items in the array gets bigger. Is there any way to optimize this any?

Answer (score 0):

You could build an object with the scores and sort the array by this values descending.

```js
const
    wordList = ["aa", "aah", "aahed", "aahing", "aahs", "aal", "aalii", "aaliis", "aals", "aardvark", "aardvarks", "aardwolf", "aardwolves", "aargh", "aarrgh", "aarrghh", "aarti", "aartis", "aas", "aasvogel", "aasvogels"],
    scores = Object.fromEntries(wordList.map(s => [
        s,
        new Set(s).size
    ]));

wordList.sort((a, b) => scores[b] - scores[a]);

console.log(wordList);
console.log(scores);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```